Package lettrine and tex4ebook with error
When using the package lettrine and tex4ebook with the following MWE, it leads to an error message:
Package xkeyval Error: `slope' undefined in families `L'.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Testdocument_lettrine-ebook.tex    1496  
 Package xkeyval Error: `nindent' undefined in families `L'.

This is the MWE:
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{tex4ebook}

\begin{document}
    
\lettrine[lines=2,slope=-1.0em,findent=0.2em,nindent=-5pt]{V}{on} allen Artefakten, die Archäologen

\end{document}

Is there a fix to this?

Try this version of lettrine.4ht. It should define all keys recognized by lettrine:
% lettrine.4ht (2018-11-05-14:51), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2012-2018 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2018-11-05-14:51}

\NewConfigure{lettrine}{7}
\define@key{L}{ante}{\def\LH:ante{#1}}%
\define@key{L}{findent}{\def\LH:findent{#1}}%
\define@key{L}{lhang}{\def\LH:lhang{#1}}%
\define@key{L}{lines}{\def\LH:lines{#1}}%
\define@key{L}{slope}{}
\define@key{L}{depth}{}
\define@key{L}{loversize}{}
\define@key{L}{lraise}{}
\define@key{L}{nindent}{}
\define@key{L}{novskip}{}
\define@key{L}{image}{}
\define@key{L}{grid}{}
\define@key{L}{realheight}{}
\define@key{L}{refstring}{}
\define@key{L}{refstring}{}
\define@key{L}{optionsfile}{}




\def\reset:LH:keys{\let\LH:ante\@empty
    \def\LH:lines{2}%
    \def\LH:lhang{0}%
    \def\LH:findent{0pt}}
\reset:LH:keys
%
\def\@lettrine[#1]#2#3{\setkeys{L}{#1}%
     \def\HlettrineChar{#2}%
     \def\HlettrineString{#3}%
     \a:lettrine
     \ifx\LH:ante\@empty\else\f:lettrine\LH:ante\g:lettrine\fi
     \c:lettrine
      \HCode{<span class="lettrine-}#2\HCode{">}#2\HCode{</span>}
     \b:lettrine\d:lettrine#3\e:lettrine
     \reset:LH:keys}
%
% a: before lettrine
% b: after lettrine
% c: before letter
% d: between letter and string
% e: after string
% f: before ante
% g: after ante
%
\Configure{lettrine}
   {\HCode{<span class="lettrine">}}
   {\HCode{</span>}}
%
   {\HCode{<span class="lettrine-letter">}}
   {\HCode{</span><span class="lettrine-line">}}
   {\HCode{</span>}}
%
   {\HCode{<span class="lettrine-ante">}}
   {\HCode{</span>}}
%
% Define default Css
%
\Css{.lettrine{float: left;
    line-height: 0.7; 
    margin-left: -0.1em;
    margin-bottom: -.5em; margin-right: 0.2em;
    }}
\Css{.lettrine-ante{vertical-align: top;}}
\Css{.lettrine-letter{font-style: normal;
    font-size: 4em; color: gray;}}
%
\Css{.lettrine-A{margin-right: 0.3em;}}
\Css{.lettrine-A + .lettrine-line{margin-left: -0.4em;}}
\Css{.lettrine-J{line-height: 1; margin-right: 0;}}
\Css{.lettrine-H, .lettrine-I, .lettrine-N, .lettrine-U{margin-right: 0;}}
\Css{.lettrine-V{}}
\Css{.lettrine-V + .lettrine-line{margin-left: 0.3em;}}
\Css{.lettrine-Q{padding-bottom: 1em;margin-top: -0.6em;}}
\Css{.lettrine-line{font-variant: small-caps;}}
\Css{p.indent{text-indent: 0em;}}

\Hinput{lettrine}
\endinput

This is the result:


Great, Michal, in the MWE it works, no errors. Probably in my bigger book project it works too. Thank you so much.

@Thomkrates that's good to hear! I will update TeX4ht sources, so the fix is available in TeX Live soon.
